# Verifying connectivity of a graph in O(n^2)

Tags: java, breadth-first-search

I trying to solve the following problem in O(n^2):

> We have vertices which represents cities and a textfile containing an edge on each line. How many roads do we need to build to
>   make the graph connected - you can travel by road to each city?

Basically, at the start, we have just the vertices. As we read the textfile, we add a new edge each time we read a new line and we should decide after how many edges added is our graph now connected.

An example: An example:  we have 5 vertices, A, B, C, D, E. In the textfile, we have defined these edges: A-B, B-C, A-C, B-D, C-D, A-D, B-E, C-E. The graph have been made connected after building 7 edges, while we have only 5 vertices when we start (5 components).

I solved it the following way: I'm calling the BFS algorithm after adding each edge to the graph until the graph is connected and counting the number of BFS calls. However, since the BFS itself has a time complexity of O(n^2) and I'm calling it n-times, I have a worstcase time complexity near O(n^3).

How would I solve this issue in O(n^2)?

Thanks!

Comment: What is `n` here? The number of vertices or the number of edges?

Comment: Please show your attempt (maybe your version is already more efficient than you think). The solution should be more or less clear after you draw several examples by hand.

Comment: @dyukha I shared my code, I'm using a custom library for graphs, but it should be all straight-forward and well-understandable. Thanks

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I already have vertices defined in a textfile. I have in text file with each line containing new road road (new edge). I'm trying to decide after how many roads built the graph will be connected.

Comment: @Henry Added my code. In worst case I run BFS the same number of times as the number of edges in my graph. So N should be the number of edges.

Comment: this problem can be easily solved in O(n)

Comment: @AlexSalauyou could you help me with the solution? O(n^2) is fine for now, but I would be glad to see your O(n) solution

Comment: Hint: the number of roads to build directly depends on the number of connected components. So you should find the latter. It's possible to do this with multiple bfs-s, so that total complexity will be `O(|E|)`.

Comment: @dyukha Thanks. Just to clarify if I understand correctly. I should find the number of components after adding each edge (which can be done in O(n) according to wikipedia), so when calling the algorithm n-times, I get the total time complexity of O(n^2)?

Comment: No, you should just find the number of connected components (without adding edges or doing anything else). It's the only thing you have to find, since from it you can figure out the number of edges to add. This will give you time `O(E)`, which is also `O(V^2)`.

Comment: @dyukha I think I understand. But imagine this situation: we have 5 vertices, A, B, C, D, E. In the textfile, we have defined these edges: A-B, B-C, A-C, B-D, C-D, A-D, B-E, C-E. The graph have been made connected after building 7 edges, while we have only 5 vertices when we start (5 components).

Comment: And, just in case, I would use DFS, since it's simpler. BFS is useful when you try to find a distance in unweighted graph, and it's not the case here.

Comment: Oh, I'm very sorry, I misunderstood the problem. You need this data structure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure. This link may be better: https://cp-algorithms.com/data_structures/disjoint_set_union.html

Comment: @dyukha Thanks, I will look at it. Also edited the post with my example.

Comment: @dyukha I created the following algorithm: Add all edges to the graph and set the order they are being added in as their weight. Then run a MST algorithm, and the highest weight of an edge used in my spanning tree outputed by the MST algorithm is the number of roads I need to build.

Do you think there would be any counter-examples? I failed to found any.

Comment: Well, I think it should work (good work!), but it's also a weird view. DSU solves MST, and you use MST to solve your problem, OK. But DSU can solve your problem directly, you don't need MST as an intermediate. Just process your edges in the order they arrive, and then merge the components. Stop when the entire graph is merged.

Comment: @dyukha "just in case, I would use DFS, since it's simpler. BFS is useful when you try to find a distance in unweighted graph, and it's not the case here." - a bit weird reasoning, both of them are suitable for finding the number of connected components and both have the same complexity